# How to create optimized schedule that avoids duplicates

Tags: python, optimization

I've got a list of games between teams that takes place over a sixteen day period:

```
| Date | Game                        |
|------|-----------------------------|
| 1    | hot ice vs playerz          |
| 1    | caps vs quiet storm         |
| 1    | slick ice vs blizzard       |
| 1    | flow vs 4x4's               |
| 2    | avalanche vs cold force     |
| 2    | freeze vs in too deep       |
| 2    | game spot vs rare air       |
| 2    | out of order vs cold as ice |
| 3    | playerz vs avalanche        |
| 3    | quiet storm vs freeze       |
| 3    | blizzard vs game spot       |
| 3    | 4x4's vs out of order       |
| 14   | freeze vs avalanche         |
| 14   | out of order vs game spot   |
| 14   | in too deep vs cold force   |
| 14   | cold as ice vs rare air     |
| 15   | blizzard vs quiet storm     |
| 15   | playerz vs 4x4's            |
| 15   | slick ice vs caps           |
| 15   | hot ice vs flow             |
| 16   | game spot vs freeze         |
| 16   | avalanche vs out of order   |
| 16   | rare air vs in too deep     |
| 16   | cold force vs cold as ice   |
```

There are 16 teams that make up this schedule, and what I'd like to do in Python is find all of the 8 game combinations that allow me to "see" each team once. The only limitation is that I can only see one game per day. At this point all I can think of is a ton of nested for loops that generates all possible schedules, and then checking each one after to see if it is valid. A valid schedule is one that has one game per date and sees each team once.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at itertools permutations?

Comment: I have but the issue is with 16 dates with 4 games each date it is a massive number of permutations.

Comment: It is a nice exercise to formulate this as a CP (Constraint Programming) or MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) model. That would be better than complete enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a backtracking algorithm to iterate through different combinations  of matches and filtering them according to the constraints you mentioned.

First step would be to format your data into a collection like a python `list` or `dict`.  Then implement a recursive backtracking algorithm that selects one match per day, and checks to make sure the chosen match doesn't include teams you have already selected.

Here is a rough example that uses the data you provided in your question:

```
def combinations(matches, day, schedules, current):
    """Backtracking function for selecting unique schedules."""
    # base case when you have a match from each day
    if day > max(matches.keys()):  
        schedules.append(current[:])
        return
    # skip over days where there are no matches
    while day not in matches:
        day += 1
    # select one match for the current date
    for i in range(len(matches[day])):
        teams = matches[day][i]
        current_teams = [j for i in current for j in i]
        # check if the teams are already in the current schedule
        if teams[0] in current_teams or teams[1] in current_teams: 
            continue
        del matches[day][i]
        # recursive case
        combinations(matches, day + 1, schedules, current + [teams])
        matches[day].insert(i,teams)
    return




def format(inp):
    """Formats input data into a dictionary."""
    lines = inp.split("\n")[2:]     # split lines of input data
    matches = [(line.split("|")[1:-1]) for line in lines]
    schedule = {}
    # add matches to dict with date as key and matches as value.
    for day, match in matches:
        day = int(day.strip())
        teams = match.strip().split(" vs ")
        try:
            schedule[day].append(teams)
        except KeyError:
            schedule[day] = [teams]
    ideal = []
    # use backtracking algorithm to get desired results
    combinations(schedule, 1, ideal, [])
    show_schedules(ideal)


def show_schedules(results):
    for i, x in enumerate(results):
        print(f"Schedule {i+1}")
        for day, match in enumerate(x):
            print(f"Day: {day+1} - {match[0]} vs. {match[1]}")
        print("\n")


format(inp)  # <- entry point:`inp` is the pre-formatted data `str`
```

It's not exactly the most elegant code... :) With the example data this algorithm generates 32 unique schedules of 6 games. The output looks something like this but for each day of matches:

```
Schedule 1
Day: 1 - hot ice vs. playerz
Day: 2 - avalanche vs. cold force
Day: 3 - quiet storm vs. freeze
Day: 4 - out of order vs. game spot
Day: 5 - slick ice vs. caps
Day: 6 - rare air vs. in too deep


Schedule 2
Day: 1 - hot ice vs. playerz
Day: 2 - avalanche vs. cold force
Day: 3 - 4x4's vs. out of order
Day: 4 - cold as ice vs. rare air
Day: 5 - blizzard vs. quiet storm
Day: 6 - game spot vs. freeze
```

For more information on backtracking here are a few external resources or there are countless examples here on stack overflow.

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/recursion/recursion-and-backtracking/tutorial/

http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/02-backtracking.pdf

Comment: This looks a great solution - only issue is when I used the full schedule (more than that is in the original post) I get no results.

Comment: Did you surround the data in quotes and assign it to a variable?

Comment: Yes I did. I also checked that `matches` looked the same in the `format()` function. It just doesn't return any results with 64 games like it does with 24 .

Comment: hmmm I am not sure why that would be.  If you post the full data I can help you debug it.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RealJWise/b5b6ef0854d4457a154c989290130237/raw/7466fa75b987f08b500078a22c7f0725493744bc/gistfile1.txt) is the full text

Comment: I see why, It's because the current code filters out teams if it has already included them in the schedule, and since there are not enough teams to only see each one once and only once it gives up before it gets to the last day.  Let me make some adjustments

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense - thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242834/discussion-between-alexpdev-and-justin).